# What is mutate() doing here. I don't understand

Tags: r, dplyr

Self taught coder here with no cs background. It seems like I run into problems like this all the time where I don't understand really what is happening behind the scenes with the tidy verse functions I use. I need someone to explain why this isn't working in a way that I will understand.

I'm trying to run this code:
`df2.p<- df2 %>% mutate(across(4:9,~./weight))`

I understand this code to mean "divide columns 4:9 of df2 by the column named weight which is also in df2"

I get this error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
> x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 52.
> ℹ Input `..1` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.
> ℹ Input `..1` must be size 52 or 1, not 42021.

I've looked at the size of df2. Not sure what is going on.

class(df2) "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
dim(df2) is 52 x  10

code that created df2 is:

```
df2<- df1.w %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  summarise(weight.s= sum(weight, na.rm= TRUE),
            native.s= sum(Native, na.rm= TRUE),
            asian.s= sum(Asian, na.rm= TRUE),
            black.s= sum(Black, na.rm= TRUE),
            pacisland.s= sum(`Pacific Islander`, na.rm= TRUE),
              middle.s= sum(`Middle Eastern`, na.rm= TRUE),
              white.s= sum(White, na.rm= TRUE),
              raceo.s= sum(`Race Other`, na.rm= TRUE), 
            na.rm= TRUE
              )
```

I created df2 from a df1.w that has 42021 rows. I grouped these rows by state to get to 52 rows. It seems that mutate() is ungrouping df2 and looking at it as df1.w somehow. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Can you show the `packageVersion('dplyr')` Can you try `df2 %>% ungroup %>% mutate(across(4:9,~./weight))` or specify `.groups = 'drop'` in the `summarise`

Comment: packageVersion('dplyr') 
[1] ‘1.0.4’

Comment: I also use `1.0.4` and it is working fine with this data `mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% summarise(across(everything(), sum)) %>% mutate(across(4:7, ~ ./carb))`

Comment: Not positive I'm using .groups= 'drop' correctly 

Do I just add it to the end of my df2 code?
``` 
              white.s= sum(White, na.rm= TRUE),
              raceo.s= sum(`Race Other`, na.rm= TRUE), 
            na.rm= TRUE,
            .groups = 'drop'
              )
```
This resulted in the same error.

Comment: I'll try replicating with mtcars and see if I can get it to work

Comment: The easiest is to use `ungroup` without changing your code.

Comment: I think the reason is clear. You don't have a 'weight' column in 'df2' as summarise would returnn only the summarised columns and the grouping one.  But, somehow, the 'weight' was found from the global env which is of length 42021

Comment: ungroup didn't work either, gave the same error but your mtcar example helped me figure out a way that seems to have worked!
df1.p<- df1.w %>% group_by(state) %>% summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm= TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(across(4:9,~./weight))

Comment: After the `summarise` individually,  the 'weight' was not present.  With `summarise(across`, you are also summing the weight column, and the `mutate` is now doing the division on the summed weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OP's post, the `summarise` didn't do the `sum` on 'weight' and thus the column was not present in the output 'df2' because `summarise` returns only the summarised columns and the grouping columns.  We could use `across` with `everything` to do the `sum` on all the columns and then do the `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df1.w %>%
   group_by(state) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm= TRUE)) %>% 
   mutate(across(4:9,~./weight))
```

The error may have happened because 'weight' as an object may have been created in the global env as part of the original object